# Update a TextView in android with for loop and 1000 millisecond delay

Tags: android

I cannot make a simple program to update the UI.

What I am looking to do is create a timer in a for loop that is initiated on a button click

```
public void buttonClick(View v);

for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    textView.setText(i+"");

    try{
        thread.sleep(1000);
        catch{(yadayadayada)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a counter in a for loop to update a text view with a one millisecond delay.

My second try and still no good

```
package com.example.dbq;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    TextView tv1;
    Button b1;
    int n=1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        b1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for(int i=0;i<100;i++){ 
                    Runnable r=new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tv1.setText(n +" runs");
                        }
                    };

                    mHandler.post(r);
                    mHandler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
                    n++;
                }
            }
        }); //end onclick
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is that try-catch block...Try learn about basics of java

Comment: Could you specify your problem? Whats exactly the problem?

Comment: Thread.sleep(); will not produce accurate delay..it keeps varying

Comment: I think the try catch is for the Thread.sleep() which may throw an InterruptedException, and so must be wrapped in a try catch.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `thread.sleep` - you do not need to sleep your thread - you need update your UI at certain intervals and this is something different. Simply use `Handler`, then create `Runnable` that either updates your UI or calls the methods to do so and finally post your `Runnable` using `Handler.postDelayed()`. To keep the timer work, your `Runnable` have to post itself again, but that's shall be pretty obvious. And remember to remove your queued runnable when you are going to leave your fragment/activity

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer scheduled at a fixed rate. The below updated text view with a count which is incremented every second.

Remember to update text view on the UI thread and cancel the timer whenever required.

```
    _tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textView1 );
```

On Button click initiate a timer. Start button to start a timer.

```
    _t = new Timer(); 
    _t.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                _count++;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
                 {
                  public void run() 
                  { 
                     _tv.setText(""+_count);
                 }
                 });
            }
        }, 1000, 1000 );
```

Have another button stop to cancel the timer

```
        _t.cancel();
```

You can also use a handler as suggested by WebnetMobile

Comment: still no good, tired a handler didnt do as i wanted, it counted in the background and posted 101